# What are the major points during database design?

Tags: database

I'm refactoring/rebuilding my old shop system and would like to know, what are major aspects that I should pay attention too during this developing stage. My previous system was quite a crap, so in fact I think more of the new system as a brand new, not refactored old one.

Now to the point. If anyone could explain this part to me regardless of it (system) future theme. Will it be a shop or a blog or etc. Are there any main criteria, that should be met with high attention?

Thank you all for help? Hope this question is not too abstract.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are 10 high-level things you should consider, to get started, in no particular order:

1. Normalization (Third normal form is probably sufficient)
2. Consistent and standard naming of objects
3. Proper use of foreign keys
4. Deciding what to use for primary keys (do you want to use an artificial value such as an integer ID value?)
5. Proper use of indexing, with appropriate use of covering indexes as necessary. Be careful to avoid duplicate / redundant / overlapping indexes.
6. Carefully consider whether you want to use triggers (they are a good thing to avoid if possible).
7. Be very careful with views and table-valued UDFs that calls scalar valued UDFs. This can really get you into trouble, performance wise, if you're not paying attention to what you're doing.
8. To what extent do you want business logic in your database versus application code (such as C#, Java etc.). This includes the use of check constraints.
9. Come up with a consistent commenting / documentation schema for stored procs, UDFs, triggers etc.
10. Do you need to track who made inserts / updates / deletes? This can be supported a couple different ways in schema, some of the quite poor IMO (such as keeping a DeletedFlag column in each table).

Comment: Add: what are the required security and privacy constraints on the data - and how will you control them.

Comment: @Randy Minder could you explain in plain english "Third normal form". I read about on wikipedia in my own language and in english, but I still don't have clear picture. I would much appreciate if you could.

Comment: @Eugene - There is no way I can explain 3NF in the 550 characters I have left. There are plenty of sources on the Internet that can explain it well.

Comment: @Randy Minder got it. For other users who have same problem with 3NF I guess it would be a good article to read for them http://goo.gl/4Lozz.

Answer (score 1):

For starters, I'd suggest cost of database licenses, hosting, expected bandwidth (query) requirements, expected types / volume of data to be stored, consider how is the database being queried (local or web) - ultimately internal or customer facing, i.e is millisecond performance vital.